# VBA to Transpose Data

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a dataset that I’m trying to reorient but Excel’s transpose function won’t work for what I’m trying to do.  I do want to transpose the original data from rows to columns but instead I’m hoping to stack the data from each row of the original data into a single column in a separate sheet.  In other words, if I have an array made up of 3 rows and 3 columns, I want to copy and paste the data so that the 9 cells of the original array become a 1 by 9 array in a separate sheet.

My VBA skills are elementary at best and I’ve attempted to write a macro with a For Next loop but just cannot seem to get it right.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will convert a range of cells into a **unidimensional** array:

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim MiMatriz() As Integer
Dim MiPos As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set rngSource = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

ReDim MiMatriz(1 To 1, 1 To rngSource.Cells.Count)

For Each rng In rngSource.Cells
    MiPos = (((rng.Row - rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1) - 1) * rngSource.Columns.Count) + (rng.Column - rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Column + 1)
    MiMatriz(1, MiPos) = rng.Value
Next rng

For i = 1 To rngSource.Cells.Count
    Debug.Print "Index:(1," & i & ")", MiMatriz(1, i)
Next i

Erase MiMatriz
Set rngSource = Nothing
```

[image]

The output I get when executing this code is:

```
Index:(1,1)    1 
Index:(1,2)    2 
Index:(1,3)    3 
Index:(1,4)    4 
Index:(1,5)    5 
Index:(1,6)    6 
Index:(1,7)    7 
Index:(1,8)    8 
Index:(1,9)    9
```