# How to transpose and then stack ever other column with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

First time coding in VBA, stumped on how to both transpose and then stack columns in one step.

I have a dataset that is 14 columns wide, and an indeterminate number of rows tall. I need to sort them in the order shown in the image example of 1 through 14

[image: Dataset]

I already tried running the code provided [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262609/vba-to-transpose-data).

But, I'm getting stuck trying to reconfigure it to my needs, or how to paste the indexed data out as a new column

Edit: Code that can sort integers

```
Sub Depth_Width_Sort()

Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim MiMatriz() As Long
Dim MiPos As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set rngSource = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

ReDim MiMatriz(1 To 1, 1 To rngSource.Cells.Count)

For Each rng In rngSource.Cells
    MiPos = (((rng.Row - rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1) - 1) * rngSource.Columns.Count) + (rng.Column - rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Column + 1)
    MiMatriz(1, MiPos) = rng.Value
Next rng

For i = 1 To rngSource.Cells.Count Step 2
    Cells((i + 1) / 2, 16).Value = MiMatriz(1, i)
Next i

For i = 2 To rngSource.Cells.Count Step 2
    Cells(i / 2, 17).Value = MiMatriz(1, i)
Next i

Erase MiMatriz

Set rngSource = Nothing
```

And here is an example of the data sorted
[image]

Comment: With more fiddling around I managed to get the sorting method down with the code in the edit. However, I am stuck on two minor things. 
1. The output shows as 0 for values smaller than one
2. How do I start the sort one row below the headers

Comment: With Office 365: `=WRAPROWS(TOROW(A:N,3,FALSE),2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with some effort, I finally managed to get the code to work as I intended. However, @Scott Craner in the comments above has a much more elegant solution using a single Excel function, with the one drawback being it cannot ignore headers.

```
Sub Depth_Width_Sort()

Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim MiMatriz() As Variant
Dim MiPos As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set rngSource = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

ReDim MiMatriz(1 To 1, 1 To rngSource.Cells.Count)

For Each rng In rngSource.Cells
    MiPos = (((rng.Row - rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1) - 1) * rngSource.Columns.Count) + (rng.Column - rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Column + 1)
    MiMatriz(1, MiPos) = rng.Value
Next rng

For i = 1 To rngSource.Cells.Count - 14 Step 2

    Cells(1 + (i + 1) / 2, 17).Value = (i + 1) / 2
    
    If MiMatriz(1, i + 14) > 0 And MiMatriz(1, i + 15) > 0 Then
    
        Cells(1 + (i + 1) / 2, 18).Value = MiMatriz(1, i + 14)
        Cells(1 + (i + 1) / 2, 19).Value = MiMatriz(1, i + 15)
        
    End If
Next i

Erase MiMatriz

Set rngSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand you correctly and if it's OK with you to use a bubble sort, maybe you want to have a look the code like below :

```
Sub test()
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Temp As Variant
    
'put each value of the data into array
    For Each cell In Range("A1:N10") 'the range of data, change if needed
        ReDim Preserve myArray(i)
        myArray(i) = cell.Value: i = i + 1
    Next

'sorting the array
For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(myArray)
        If myArray(i) > myArray(j) Then
            Temp = myArray(j)
            myArray(j) = myArray(i)
            myArray(i) = Temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'put the result starting from cell AA1
i = 1: j = 27
For Each el In myArray
    Cells(i, j).Value = el
    If i = 14 Then j = j + 1: i = 1 Else i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Array sorting code is from this [link](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-bubble-sort-macro-to-sort-array/)

Data sample :
[image]

Result : 
[image]